# Complex integral - winding number

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

[image]

i want to find $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int _\gamma \frac{1}{z}dz$$

well $0$'s winding number is $2$, so $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int _\gamma \frac{1}{z}dz=2$

but when I explicity calculate the integral I get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int _\gamma \frac{1}{z}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}(\log(z)\lvert ^{z=-1}_{z=3}+\log(z)\lvert ^{z=\sqrt 2}_{z=-1}+\log(z)\lvert ^{z=-\sqrt 5}_{z=\sqrt 2}+\log(z)\lvert ^{z=3}_{z=-\sqrt 5})=\\ \frac{1}{2\pi i}(\log |-1|+i\pi-\log 3+\log \sqrt 2 -\log |-1|-i\pi+\log |-\sqrt 5|+i\pi-\log \sqrt 2  +\\+\log 3-\log |-\sqrt 5|-i\pi)=0$$

whats going on here?

Comment: thank u lone upvoter! one more!!

Comment: Well, my upvote wasn't just in sympathy: it was also due to the effort you showed in posting your work! ;-)

Comment: amwhy oohh I think you missed the first version of the question. I was asking for upvotes in order to post the picture. but thank you very much

Comment: No, I saw the first version: even without the picture, it was clear you showed some effort!

Comment: The path indicated winds twice around $0$, so you should get $2$ as result.

Comment: @DanielFischer thnk you, I will edit the question because the problem persists even with that correction

Comment: I think the comments under Michael's answer indicate that the matter is resolved. Am I right?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The imaginary part of logarithm increases as you go around the origin.
It is the angle between z and the positive real axis.
As you go around from 3 to -1 to $\sqrt{2}$, that angle increases from 0 to $\pi$ to $2\pi$.  So the imaginary part of $\log(\sqrt{2})$ is $2\pi$.
$\log x$ has lots of complex values, in the same way that $\sqrt{x}$ has two values.  By following the path $\gamma$, you can follow which value is relevant to your problem.
Think of it like a multistory car-part.  Going around the origin puts you on a different level.

Comment: I think the imaginary parts will cancel out and I'm still getting $0$

Comment: following your idea, if the imaginary part of $\log -1$ is $\pi$ shouldnt the imaginary part of $\log -5$ be $3\pi$?

Comment: and then shouldn't the "last $\log 3$" imaginary part be $4\pi$?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: I think this is a nice, clear answer. +1

Answer (score 4):

An exaggerated idea to try to understand a little more that branch cut thingy of the logarithmic function: let us try to divide the given path in several semicircles, say

$$\begin{align*}\gamma_1&:=\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;|z-1|=2\;,\;\;\text{Im}\,(z)\ge 0\}\\
\gamma_2:&=\left\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;\left|z-\frac{\sqrt2 -1}2\right|=(\sqrt2-1)^2\;,\;\;\text{Im}\,(z)\le 0\right\}\\
\gamma_3&:=\left\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;\left|z-\frac{\sqrt2-\sqrt5}2\right|=(\sqrt2-\sqrt5)^2\;,\;\;\text{Im}\,(z)\ge 0\right\}\\
\gamma_3&:=\left\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;\left|z-\frac{3-\sqrt5}2\right|=(3-\sqrt5)^2\;,\;\;\text{Im}\,(z)\le 0\right\}\end{align*}$$

Now, in each and every case we get

$$\int\frac{dz}z=\text{Log}\,z$$

which makies things pretty simple...but with a catch, as you've been already explained: every time the (complex) logarithm completes a whole "spin" around zero we must add (or substract, depending on the spinning direction) $\,2\pi\,$ to its argument, so (**Note:** Log denotes the complex logaithm, log the real one):

$$\begin{align*}\int\limits_{\gamma_1}\frac{dz}z&=\text{Log}\,(-1)-\text{Log}\,3=\pi i-\color{red}{\log 3}\\
\int\limits_{\gamma_2}\frac{dz}z&=\text{Log}\,\sqrt2-\text{Log}\,(-1)=\frac12\log2+2\pi i-\pi i=\color{green}{\frac12\log2}+\pi i\\
\int\limits_{\gamma_3}\frac{dz}z&=\text{Log}\,(-\sqrt5)-\text{Log}\,\sqrt2=\frac12\log5+3\pi i-\frac12\log2-2\pi i=\color{blue}{\frac12\log5}-\color{green}{\frac12\log2}+\pi i\\
\int\limits_{\gamma_4}\frac{dz}z&=\text{Log}\,3-\text{Log}\,(-\sqrt5)=\log3+4\pi i-\frac12\log5-3\pi i=\color{red}{\log3}-\color{blue}{\frac12\log5}+\pi i\end{align*}$$

Now add all the above and you get, of course, $\,4\pi i\,$ ...

Comment: Since $z\mapsto \dfrac{1}{z}$ has an anderivative in $\Bbb C\setminus \{0\}$ which is an open set that contains the path $\gamma$, can't you just say: $$\int \limits_{\gamma}\dfrac{1}{z}dz=\text{Log}(\color{blue}3)-\text{Log}(3)=\log (3)+4\pi i-\log (3),$$ where the blue $\color{blue}3$ denotes the end of the path and the black $3$ denotes its origin?

Comment: I guess yes, yet that $\,4\pi i\,$ is **already** acknowledging the fact the path winds around zero twice, and the whole purpose in the above exercise is not to do it that way (say, we don't know what winding number is), just the fact we must add $\,2\pi\,$ to the logarithm each time a whole round is completed.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems.

One problem is in the use of $\log(z)$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$. $\log(z)$ cannot be defined as a continuous function on all of $\mathbb{C}$. This is part of the reason for the introduction of [Riemann Surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface). Integrating $\frac1z$ along a path that circles the origin once, counter-clockwise gives $2\pi i$; e.g. a unit circle:
$$
\begin{align}
\oint\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z}
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}e^{it}}{e^{it}}\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{i\,e^{it}\,\mathrm{d}t}{e^{it}}\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}i\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=2\pi i
\end{align}
$$
Another problem is that the contour circles the origin *twice* in a counter-clockwise direction, so the integral should be $4\pi i$.

Answer (score 0):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425203/integration-of-complex-function/425215#425215). Just note this, we parametrize gamma as $z=re^{i\theta}$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-i\theta}ie^{i\theta}d\theta = 1. $$

**Added:** What's left is just to multiply the answer by 2 to get the desired answer, since your curve encircles the origin twice counter clockwise.

Comment: I dont see how that helps. are you saying $1$ is the right answer? but what did I do wrong in my direct calculation?

Comment: is my mistake assuming that $\frac{1}{z}$ has an antiderivative on a circle containing the path? I'm confused

Comment: This is incorrect, as you are going around the singularity two times.

Comment: @Delavid: My answer gives you the technique how you do it. The only thing is left is to multiply the answer by 2 since the curve encircles the origin twice counter clochwise. This answer is exactly the same as Robjohn's answer!

Comment: @Pragabhava: Are you sure of what you are saying?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal [Pretty sure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number). Robjohn's answer address this.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal, your parametrization of $\,\gamma\,$ is completely wrong, and not only because the given path is not exactly a circle (one could do away with that pretty easily), but because your parametrization , which you chose to do with $\,0\le t\le 2\pi\,$ just revolves once around zero...Had you chosen $\,0\le t\le 4\pi\,$ and helped the OP to "shrink" its path to a "double unit circle" (meaning: the usual unit circle run twice around zero), your answer would be acceptable...imo, at least.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Taking $0\leq t\leq 4\pi$ or $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$ and multiplying by 2 gives the same answer!. As I said, Robjohn's answer is exactly the same as my answer. You can not see this.

Comment: Oh, I know that Mhenni...and *still* your parametrization is wrong and that, imo, is what must be improtant to the OP. It's not like you explaned *why* you can go around the unit circle (which doesn't even appear in the question) **once** and then multiply by two and...voila, get the correct answer. *Why?* This can be a little confussing at first visit.

Comment: In fact I hadn't seen Rob's answer before, but he at least didn't said he parametrized the OP's path so and so. He talks of **a** path that encircles zero once and etc. Nevertheless, I think his answer also can be confusing.